# A polynomial determined by two values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

From a St. Petersburg school olympiad, 11th grade.

Prove or disprove: a non constant polynomial $P$ with non-negative integer coefficients is uniquely determined by its values $P(2)$ and $P(P(2))$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

True. If $P(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ then each of the coefficients are less then $b\equiv P(2)$. Each of these coefficients can then be read off from the base-b expansion of $P(b)=P(P(2))$.

Comment: Several people seem to be answering this one at the same time (how to select a single accepted answer?). Actually, it's a common question that keeps popping up on various maths forums.

Comment: For what it's worth, Steve got there a few seconds before me.

Comment: Perhaps you can wait for the 3rd upvote and then delete. You will get a badge :-)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you deleted your answer, but I don't see any issue with having two the same. I just voted Steve up and pointed out that he did get there before before me in the comment, to be fair to him.

Comment: Oh, I like badges :)

Answer (score 11):

Look at $P(P(2))$ in base $P(2)$.  The nth place is the coefficient of $x^n$.

Steve

Comment: You don't have to sign your answers, BTW.

Comment: I don't "have" to, I want to :).  I do it on all the other forums, so force of habit.