# Guess the Polynomial

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Player ONE has a finite degree polynomial $p$ with integer coefficients in mind whose domain is the reals.

Player TWO gets to ask Player ONE to evaluate the polynomial at two points $x_0,x_1$ and Player ONE responds with $p(x_0)=y_0$, and $p(x_1)=y_1$.

With this information, can Player TWO guess the polynomial?

I have figured out the solution to this problem, but I wanted to post the problem on SE so that you guys could have fun with it. Cheers!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446130

Answer (score 5):

Ask for $x_0=\pi$ and ignore your second chance.

Comment: Yep. heheheheheh. Now if we ask that both $x_0, x_1$ cannot be transcendental ?

Comment: @Rustyn If $x_0,x_1$ must be algebraic, let $f,g\in\mathbb Z[X]$ be polynomials with $f(x_0)=g(x_1)=0$. Then we player two cannot tell apart $p$ from $p+fg$ ...

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?