# Polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients in several variables can be determined from only two values

Tags: polynomials

The following result seems to be fairly well-known.

> Suppose $p$ is a polynomial in one variable with positive integer coefficients, and suppose that $p$ is to be determined by giving several inputs in succession, which are allowed to depend on previous outputs. Then only two inputs are needed to determine $p$. [[1](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/03/27/polynomial-trick/),
>   [2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39752/43225),
>   [3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/91874/43225),
>   [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/a-polynomial-determined-by-two-values),
>   [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446130/quickest-way-to-determine-a-polynomial-with-positive-integer-coefficients),
>   [6](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29862/43225)]

Is it also well-known that it still holds when $p$ is allowed to depend on any finite number of variables?

---

Suppose $p$ depends on $v$ different variables. Take $B > p(2, \dotsc, 2)$ and $D > \log_2 p (2, \dotsc, 2)$, which are bounds on the coefficients and on the degree, respectively. Now each coefficient of $p$ can be encoded as a digit of the base-$B$ representation of
$$
p_2 = p(B^{D^0},B^{D^1}, \dotsc, B^{D^{v-1}}).
$$
More specifically, to find the coefficient of $x_0^{d_0} \dotsm x_{v-1}^{d_{v-1}}$, consider its contribution to $p_2$,
$$
(B^{D^0})^{d_0} \cdot (B^{D^1})^{d_1} \dotsm (B^{D^{v-1}})^{d_{v-1}}
  = B^{d_0 D^0 + d_1 D^1 + \dotsb + d_{v-1} D^{v-1}}.
$$
This gives a power of $B$ (and therefore a digit in $p_2$) uniquely associated to the desired coefficient precisely because $D$ exceeds the degree of $p$.

Comment: Are you asking whether your solution is correct? It seems to be, upon a quick glance.

Comment: @GregMartin This was part of an undergraduate research project. I'm wondering things like: Is it original? Is it considered trivial? Is it published somewhere such as a blog? (My advisor had not seen it before.)

Comment: I had heard the one-variable version before, as a "chestnut" problem, though I don't know where to find it published. My opinion is that most mathematicians who know the solution to the one-variable version would be able to extend it to the several-variable version, although I have no idea if that extension ever been pointed out before.

Comment: @GregMartin What's a chestnut problem?

Comment: "An old chestnut" is a common idiom: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/an+old+chestnut
(but I didn't mean to imply that it was stale or now boring - just that it had been passed around often)

Comment: Actually, only $1$ input is needed. We can just look at $p(\pi)$ and since  $\pi$ is transcendental in principle you can figure out the polynomial.